# How to response errors only in json format in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, response

As usual, Yii2 shows errors in HTML format in site/error file. How to make all errors returned as JSON format?

Comment: please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Error Actions](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-handling-errors#using-error-actions)

Comment: @Sfili_81 thank you, next time will be better)

Comment: @DefinitelynotRafal thank you for your attention but, in your link, I found out only customize errors response if global response format is JSON in the project. In my case, I want to change only error's response format

Comment: @AhrorGaibnazarov You wanted to *"all errors returned as JSON format"*. You get that only by creating your own error handler or by editing the default error handler (i would suggest you, you dont edit the core files). If you want it to be returned as JSON then you need your new error handler to do so. How do you do that? Check my link again and look at what happens at the actionError method ... it renders a file (this is what you get shown, this is your html format). So in your case you dont want a file to be rendered. You want the data to be output as a json string.

Comment: `Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;` in your action

Comment: @DefinitelynotRafal thank you for directing me to the answer with documentation. I have created actionError() in the SiteController and inside it returned $exception from errorHandler. Additionally, in the action, I added vvpanchev 's comment to return JSON format. After that, I got what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the format of your response in a certain action of your controller, for example:

```
public function actionYourAction($id_survey) {
    \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    // return JSON Array or JSON Object here.
}
```

But in your case, you must first overwrite the error action, as explained here:
https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-erroraction